# Cloning Drupal site using desktop application stuck forever

Tags: drupal, acquia

I am trying to clone a Drupal website using Acquia Dev desktop application. It has been more than 6-7 hours and there is absolutely no progress. The website is around 5.5GB. I tried to force stop the process and relaunched it. Again even after 5-6 hours, there is no progress.

[image]

What do I do? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tracked the processes. When the app would get stuck, I would see a new terminal process begin and the network usage of the app would drop to 0. So I checked the terminal. The issue was with my .bash_profile file and the terminal wouldn’t allow the commands to execute. Fixed the issue and the site got finally downloaded.

I used [iStat menus](https://bjango.com/mac/istatmenus/) to check the network usage of the application.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any application to clone your site. Just copy all the files, copy database and change `settings.php` file (usually is located at `sites/default/settings.php`) so database account data match your new database server. Simple as that. To speed up files transfer if you have shell access you can archive all files, download the archive and then unpack at new location (server).

You can also use "Backup & migrate" module to make site archive (files and/or database).